# ListPicker Data Binding and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

So I have two ListPickers, `Device Type` and `Device Name`.

If I select *Tablet* in `Device Type`, I want the `Device Name` ListPicker to show options like *Ipad*, *Dell Venue 8*, etc.

If I select *Phone* in `Device Type`, I want the `Device Name` ListPicker to show options like *Iphone*, *Samsung Galaxy*, etc and so on.

So how can I go about making a data binding between these two ListPickers and also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so changes in one ListPicker are dynamically reflected in the other?

Comment: Take a look at [ask].  It helps if you have some sample code.

Comment: Binding two combos is a very common task and there are many duplicates out there.  Even WPF examples would apply, as the pattern is still exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :
    In your xaml :

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="DeviceType" ItemSource="{Binding DeviceTypeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeviceType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="DeviceName" ItemSource="{Binding DeviceNameList}" />
```

In your code :

```
public class ClassName : NotifyChangements
{
    private YourType selectedDeviceType;
    public YourType SelectedDeviceType
    {
        get { return selectedDeviceType; }
        set
        {
            selectedDeviceType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceType");
            MAJDeviceName();
        }
    }

    // Later in code.
    public void MAJDeviceName()
    {
        // Add code here that fill the DeviceNameList according to the SelectedDeviceType.
    }
}
```

And for the NotifyChangements class :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class NotifyChangements : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        public bool NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(ref T variable, T valeur, [CallerMemberName] string property = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(variable, valeur)) return false;
            variable = valeur;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(property);
            return (true);
        }
    }
```

You also have to add the `List<YourType> DeviceNameList` as an attribute and call the `NotifyPropertyChanged("DeviceNameList")` in the setter of that attribute in order to make it bind the datas.

Moreover, I'll let you change the variable and type names as you haven't provided any code samples !